# Security issues when using Amazon S3 file hosting for Flex modules/swfs

Tags: apache-flex, security, flash, crossdomain.xml

What kind of security issues am I going to run into when hosting a Flex site (with multiple modules) using Amazon S3's hosting?

Can I even communicate between two different swfs if they're loaded from two different subdomains? (These will be modules)

I dont yet know if i would host all modules on S3 or just some. For testing impact to server load it would certainly be easier to just test hosting our main .swf (public website)

I know about crossdomain.xml for web servcies - does this apply for cross domain swf communication too?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to give security access to the SWFs because they are not from the same domains. The approach is similar to the crossdomain for webservices except that you need to place the following method call "[security.allowDomain](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002104.html)" instead of crossdomain XMLs.

In order for the SWFs from different domains to examine and modify variables, objects, properties, methods (cross-domain scripting), you would need to call "security.allowDomain".

The Adobe documentation covers it in great details.